# jqGrid: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'integer': object is null or undefined

Tags: jqgrid

I get the above exception at this line of code of jqGrid.src.js

```
fmt = $.jgrid.formatter.integer || {};
```

I can't for the life of me tell you what that means or why I can't get the damn thing to work.  I suspect it has to do with how I am building my json object.

```
        for(int j = rowstart; (j <= rowend && variable.Template.Count > j); j++){
            PatientACOModel patMod = variable.Template[j];
            var rowData = new{
                id = patMod.EncounterId,
                cell = new {
                    MRN = patMod.MRN,
                    Hospital_Fin = patMod.HospitalFinNumber,
                    First_Name = patMod.FirstName,
                    Last_Name = patMod.LastName,
                    Date_of_birth = patMod.DateOfBirth
                }
            };
            al.Add(rowData);
        }

        var griddata = new {
            total = variable.Template.Count % rows > 0 ? (variable.Template.Count / rows) + 1 : (variable.Template.Count / rows),
            page = page,
            records = al.Count,
            rows = al.ToArray()
        };
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong?  It looks like everything is set up correctly?

**UPDATE**
This would be the json data that is being sent back to my jqGRid... These are just a small selection of rows, and columns.  Am I missing something here?

```
{"total": 2,
"page": 1,
"records": 15,
"rows": [{
    "id": 2148,
    "cell": {
        "MRN": "840134833",
        "Hospital_Fin": "987141516",
        "First_Name": "YELLOW",
        "Last_Name": "CRAYON",
        "Date_of_birth": "\/Date(1253160000000)\/"          
    }
},
{
    "id": 1898,
    "cell": {
        "MRN": "785528039",
        "Hospital_Fin": "6669511596226",
        "First_Name": "RAYFIELD",
        "Last_Name": "BOYD",
        "Date_of_birth": "\/Date(-720298800000)\/"
    }
}]}
```

Comment: Check that you have valid JSON but the error sounds more to do with the format you are assigning to the numbers in the grid.

Comment: I don't do any formatting of the numbers in the grid.  I just take the strings as they are?  Could it be the Date Functions there?  Those don't look like standard date values to me?

Answer (score 6):

To eliminate this error, you need to make sure that you are **including** the localization file

```
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
```

**before the jqGrid** file.  That eliminated the problem for me.

Comment: I try and contribute positively to humanity.  Glad you found my comment and question useful.